# Grouping by Different Date Ranges

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am trying to find the most efficient method to query my table and build a hash of the amount of users created between now and different date ranges. This hash should appear as follows...

```
{"7 Days" => 8, "1 Month" => 15, "3 Months" => 45, "12 Months" => 108, "Total" => 333}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make a view in a database in a way:

```
select (select count from now till now-7 days) as 7days,
       (select count from now till now - 1month) as 1month, etc
```

and then query that view in your app

Comment: Thanks @lx00st. I would ideally like a rails query I can use in my controller.

Comment: if you have a view you can make an ActiveRecord model for it so you can rails-query it)

Comment: I think for my usage. Setting up a SQL view is probably a bit overkill. I was really looking for an efficient group query that isn't too intensive on the database.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to create a scope..
An example of a scope that returned all instances less than a month old would be as follows:

```
scope :1month, -> { where("created_at < ?", 1.month.ago) }
```

You could then chain it with count.

```
n = MyClass.1month.count
```